# Can't get varnish to see backend

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I installed Varnish locally on OSX to test it out. I have a working backend running on localhost:8085 that returns a 200. I installed varnish with Brew but don't have the Brew service running, I instead run Varnish with

```
varnishd -n /usr/local/var/varnish -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:8085 -a 127.0.0.1:8090 -F
```

which prints

```
Debug: Platform: Darwin,17.5.0,x86_64,-jnone,-sdefault,-sdefault,-hcritbit
Debug: Child (57659) Started
Info: Child (57659) said Child starts
```

and creates a `vcl_boot.*` folder in `/usr/local/var/varnish`

When i go to `127.0.0.1:8090` I see varnish is running but just get

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed
```

My `/usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl` is pretty much the default:

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8085";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc.
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

Does anyone know what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command to run Varnish, I think you mistakenly use `-T 127.0.0.1:8085`. The `-T` switch is for:

> Offer a management interface on the specified address and port.

So you're binding the Varnish management interface to the same port as your backend. Wonder why that doesn't fail anyway.

Comment: I am running Varnish 6 and when i do the help command it says `-T address[:port]` is `CLI address` Could i have a different version to what you are seeing?

Comment: I don't think so. Just set a different port to that switch. It has nothing to do with the backend's port.

Comment: Thanks, just removed the -T and the backend port is set in the VLC, all good